# Hiring a contractor to inspect / survey / analyse my home as a whole

Tags: contractors

Last summer I hired a general contractor to do some painting, trim, and cabinetry work. During that time he told us a bit about our home, and that in the next 20 - 25 years we may need to do some more serious renovations to things like our insulation, electrical, and plumbing.

What I'm interested in doing at this point is hiring a contractor to come in, inspect our home, and do some analysis on what type of work we may need done, how soon we'll need it done, what we should prioritize, and how we should do it. Basically someone to lay down a framework to fix up our home over the next 20 - 30 years.

My question is, what type of contractor or builder would I be looking at to get something like this done? And how would I go about getting this type of quote / estimate?

Comment: Please never invite anyone into your home with a "blank check".   If you can't formulate a list of what you need to do make sure the person you are paying for advice has no long-term incentive in doing the work.    This question is the recipe for a really bad contractor experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like you want a building inspector.

Comment: Yes, start with someone who won't profit from the recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, is there a particular type or quality of inspector I should be looking for? I had the impression that some inspectors do more of a superficial analysis when an owner is readying a home to be sold.